# Python - Looping From Black to a Set Color

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, colors

I am writing a breathing effect for the `neopixel` library and need to essentially increment three numbers to create a `Color` for a set period.

I can do this pretty easily with black to white:

```
def colorBreathing(strip, color, wait_ms = 5):
# Breathing lights
for b in range(200):
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, Color(b, b, b))
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
for b in reversed(range(200)):
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, Color(b, b, b))
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
```

The question is, how would I do this with another color that the user sets? So a set color could be something like `Color(200, 180, 230)` for example.

Comment: if you have `steps = 200` then use `step_R = 200/steps`, `step_G = 180/steps`, `step_B = 230/steps` and then `Color(int(step_R*b), int(step_G*b), int(step_B*b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `steps = 200` and `(200, 180, 230)` then use

```
step_R = 200/steps 
step_G = 180/steps
step_B = 230/steps
```

and then `Color( int(step_R*b), int(step_G*b), int(step_B*b) )`

Not tested:

```
destination = (200, 180, 230)

steps = 200

step_R = destination[0]/steps
step_G = destination[1]/steps
step_B = destination[2]/steps

for x in range(steps):
    r = int(step_R*x)
    g = int(step_G*x)
    b = int(step_B*x)
    c = Color(r, g, b)
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, c)
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

for x in range(steps, -1, -1):
    r = int(step_R*x)
    g = int(step_G*x)
    b = int(step_B*x)
    c = Color(r, g, b)
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, c)
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
```

---

You can use `r += step_R` instead of `r = int(step_R * x)`

Not tested:

```
destination = (200, 180, 230)

steps = 200

step_R = destination[0]/steps
step_G = destination[1]/steps
step_B = destination[2]/steps

r = 0
g = 0
b = 0

for x in range(steps):
    c = Color(int(r), int(g), int(b))
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, c)
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
    r += step_R
    g += step_G
    b += step_B

for x in range(steps):
    r -= step_R
    g -= step_G
    b -= step_B
    c = Color(int(r), int(g), int(b))
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, c)
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
```

Comment: This works thank you! I'm using the second method. I had to reduce the steps to 100 which seems to work with every color I use.